# Page Object Model for multiple web applications

Tags: java, testing, automation, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am having a Test automation tool, now we are on to implement page object model for the automated testing of our web applications, as per my understanding page object model is good if you have only one application to test, but we are having multiple web applications to test.I just want to know is it really possible to create page object model for multiple web applications and the tool should be able to do the automated testing by using page object??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**  The Page Object model simply creates objects that represent pages.  The only real difference between testing one application and testing multiple applications is ... more pages.  The number of web applications you are testing doesn't change the fact that each application has pages that can be represented by Page Objects in your code.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is a very good idea to have POM for multiple web applications.
I would suggest creating an Automation Framework that satisfies all your needs.
You can have a dedicated package named **"page"** under which you could have multiple packages for respective web applications. e.g. mentioned below
framework
1. data (Test Data management related stuff)
2. env (Test Env Management related stuff)
3. **page** ->
**apps** ->
**app1** (Respective page classes for web-app1) ->
**app2** (Respective page classes for web-app2)
4. report
5. util